# local css stylesheet not linking

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to add my .css file, but it is not working and not applying.

But when I put the same style code in HTML it works, so the problem is links, but I think I am doing it right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0uRW.png)

I have also tried putting `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` but I know I gotta put the folder names too, so both don't work.

Also, something was wrong with linking, because I tried putting in `<img>` and it still wouldn't link or show but when I tried online image, it would link.

Comment: Hey, have you tried path in href as ../static/style.css

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @MichaelM. I uploaded an image to show the code snippet and my folder structure, not to upload the code to show code, but thanks for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the 9th line as
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">`

because u need to go back from dashboard.html use`"../"`
Then goes to the stylesheet file as "static/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

Path should be **../static/style.css** in href attribute